# Protostar Stack 0 Challenge: How to find out the buffer size from assembly code?

Tags: c, assembly

I've been trying protostar stack0 challenge and wondering how to find out the buffer size if we don't have the source code.

The original site (http://exploit-exercises.com/protostar) is no longer available, however you can still download the copy of ISO at https://download.vulnhub.com/exploitexercises/exploit-exercises-protostar-2.iso

Here is the assembly code

```
(gdb) disassemble main
Dump of assembler code for function main:
0x080483f4 <main+0>:    push   ebp
0x080483f5 <main+1>:    mov    ebp,esp
0x080483f7 <main+3>:    and    esp,0xfffffff0
0x080483fa <main+6>:    sub    esp,0x60
0x080483fd <main+9>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x5c],0x0
0x08048405 <main+17>:   lea    eax,[esp+0x1c]
0x08048409 <main+21>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],eax
0x0804840c <main+24>:   call   0x804830c <gets@plt>
0x08048411 <main+29>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x5c]
0x08048415 <main+33>:   test   eax,eax
0x08048417 <main+35>:   je     0x8048427 <main+51>
0x08048419 <main+37>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x8048500
0x08048420 <main+44>:   call   0x804832c <puts@plt>
0x08048425 <main+49>:   jmp    0x8048433 <main+63>
0x08048427 <main+51>:   mov    DWORD PTR [esp],0x8048529
0x0804842e <main+58>:   call   0x804832c <puts@plt>
0x08048433 <main+63>:   leave  
0x08048434 <main+64>:   ret    
End of assembler dump.
(gdb)
```

Based on the code, I can see the `gets` function (to read a line from stdin).

```
0x0804840c <main+24>:   call   0x804830c <gets@plt>
0x08048411 <main+29>:   mov    eax,DWORD PTR [esp+0x5c]
```

Therefore, I've set breakpoints before and after that line to see what it can do.

```
(gdb) info breakpoints 
No breakpoints or watchpoints.
(gdb) break *0x0804840c
Breakpoint 3 at 0x804840c: file stack0/stack0.c, line 11.
(gdb) break *0x08048411
Breakpoint 4 at 0x8048411: file stack0/stack0.c, line 13.
(gdb)
```

It's time to test `gets` function with random data.

```
user@protostar:~$ python -c 'print "A"*60'
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA
user@protostar:~$
```

In first scenario, I'll supply 60 * A character. I use python code as above to generate 60 A characters.

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /opt/protostar/bin/stack0 

Breakpoint 3, 0x0804840c in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff864) at stack0/stack0.c:11
11      in stack0/stack0.c
(gdb) c
Continuing.
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Breakpoint 4, main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff864) at stack0/stack0.c:13
13      in stack0/stack0.c
(gdb) i r $eip $esp $ebp
eip            0x8048411        0x8048411 <main+29>
esp            0xbffff750       0xbffff750
ebp            0xbffff7b8       0xbffff7b8
(gdb) x/40 $esp
0xbffff750:     0xbffff76c      0x00000001      0xb7fff8f8      0xb7f0186e
0xbffff760:     0xb7fd7ff4      0xb7ec6165      0xbffff778      0x41414141
0xbffff770:     0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0xbffff780:     0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0xbffff790:     0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0xbffff7a0:     0x41414141      0x41414141      0x08048400      0x00000000
0xbffff7b0:     0x08048450      0x00000000      0xbffff838      0xb7eadc76
0xbffff7c0:     0x00000001      0xbffff864      0xbffff86c      0xb7fe1848
0xbffff7d0:     0xbffff820      0xffffffff      0xb7ffeff4      0x0804824b
0xbffff7e0:     0x00000001      0xbffff820      0xb7ff0626      0xb7fffab0
(gdb) c
Continuing.
Try again?

Program exited with code 013.
(gdb)
```

I know I'll get the answer if I put more than 64 A as I've seen the source code.

```
(gdb) r
Starting program: /opt/protostar/bin/stack0 

Breakpoint 3, 0x0804840c in main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff864) at stack0/stack0.c:11
11      in stack0/stack0.c
(gdb) c
Continuing.
AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA

Breakpoint 4, main (argc=1, argv=0xbffff864) at stack0/stack0.c:13
13      in stack0/stack0.c
(gdb) i r $eip $esp $ebp
eip            0x8048411        0x8048411 <main+29>
esp            0xbffff750       0xbffff750
ebp            0xbffff7b8       0xbffff7b8
(gdb) x/40 $esp
0xbffff750:     0xbffff76c      0x00000001      0xb7fff8f8      0xb7f0186e
0xbffff760:     0xb7fd7ff4      0xb7ec6165      0xbffff778      0x41414141
0xbffff770:     0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0xbffff780:     0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0xbffff790:     0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141
0xbffff7a0:     0x41414141      0x41414141      0x41414141      0x00000041
0xbffff7b0:     0x08048450      0x00000000      0xbffff838      0xb7eadc76
0xbffff7c0:     0x00000001      0xbffff864      0xbffff86c      0xb7fe1848
0xbffff7d0:     0xbffff820      0xffffffff      0xb7ffeff4      0x0804824b
0xbffff7e0:     0x00000001      0xbffff820      0xb7ff0626      0xb7fffab0
(gdb) c
Continuing.
you have changed the 'modified' variable

Program exited with code 051.
(gdb)
```

The questions is what if I don't have the source code?

How to find out the exact buffer size?

Comment: In your question you don't show "source", but disassembly of machine code, which you can do on any binary machine code you have, so you are already not limited by source. But from that disassembly it's next to impossible to figure out exact buffer size from original source (there could have been two local arrays like `char a[30], b[30];` and with "b" unused and optimizations off, you will get similar machine code like if only single array was in source with size `char a[60];`).

Comment: Hint: The exact buffer size isn't directly what you need. You need the difference between the address passed to `gets` and the address of the instruction pointer to jump to on return.

Comment: ... but in exploit world you don't care about true size of buffer (i.e. exact look of original source), you care how much you have to overflow the buffer to hit specific bytes in stack to modify the behaviour of running app. And for that, that disassembled machine code is enough, because you can track down all instructions working with stack pointer and calculate when the `gets` will start to overwrite positions which are of interest to you. (if you understand why that buffer even is in stack memory and how the address is passed to `gets`, etc... and what else is stored in that area of mem)

Comment: The size of the buffer passed to `gets` for input can be inferred by looking at the address of the start of the buffer passed to `gets` which is `[esp+0x1c]` . A DWORD value of 0x00000000 is placed at `[esp+0x5c]` which is checked to see if it is overwritten after `gets`. So the buffer itself is 0x5c-0x1c=0x40 = 64 (decimal). The 0x000000000 after the buffer is being treated as a canary value. If it is modified then you exceeded the buffer length.

Comment: Thanks @aschepler. I believe you just shared 2 important tips here. I read about it somewhere, but still can't figure out how to do it. Could you please share the details of these 2 tips?

Comment: @ped7g in this exercise it isn't about overwriting the return address.It is about at least overwriting the canary value (variable `modified`) after the buffer so it alters the check after `gets`. The canary value in variable `modified` is being checked to see if it had been altered.

Comment: Thanks @MichaelPetch, I understand now how to get the difference between the address passed to `gets` function.

Do you have any idea about 2nd tips from @aschepler which `the address of the instruction pointer to jump to on return`?

Comment: In my opinion @aschepler has thrown a red herring into this as it doesn't matter to get an idea how long the buffer is. This is a simple test that involves the overwriting of the `modified` variable after the buffer.

Comment: Upon entering `main:` function, before executing the first instruction `push ebp`, the `esp` points at top of the stack, and the last value put into stack was "return address", so if you are in debugger, you can take note of `esp` value before `push ebp` and then watch how it evolves (each `push` will `-=4` it, `pop` will `+=4`, `call/ret` work in similar way, and then there is that `sub esp,...` reserving extra space directly for local variables. That `leave` instruction will try to restore the `esp` and `ebp` back to original values, so `ret` will hit the return address.

Comment: These things are best to try out in debugger, watching the values in registers while single stepping example code, and cross-checking that with the instruction reference guide, making sure that the theoretical instruction description fits what you see in debugger and everything is understandable. The inner mechanism of `call/ret/push/pop` is not as trivial as `mov` instruction, so it may take few more tries to re-read the descriptions and check the code in debugger...

Comment: On  side note.I haven't seen the original code, but I can infer not just the buffer size but the type of code that would have generated this: https://godbolt.org/z/F5wAZ2

Comment: Oh, sorry, I assumed this was some sort of code injection exercise. If all you need to do is control whether `main` passes the one string or the other to `puts`, that's much simpler: you just need to work out how to modify the "esp+0x5c" location it's checking immediately after `gets`.

Answer (score 0):

Im a newbie in RE but I'll try my best to answer it

```
0x080483fd <main+9>:    mov    DWORD PTR [esp+0x5c],0x0
0x08048405 <main+17>:   lea    eax,[esp+0x1c]
```

on main+9, it stores 0x0 on [esp+0x5c] and any input will be stored on buffer starting from [esp+0x1c] until [esp+0x5c]. So 0x5c-0x1c=64(decimal)